# How to differentiate between repeating events in apple calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, applescript

on OSX 10.12.4

I have a list of repeating events in my apple calendar that are set to run a applescript at certain times.  However, if i happen to be away (vacation etc.)
then when I switch my mac back on it runs all the scripts that did not run while the computer was off.  Annoying and long.
I tried to use some applescript code that checks that the script that wants to run is the one for today and today only (not for the days before etc.), but i could not find a way to discriminate between repeating events:  they all have the same properties!

Any one has a way around?
thanks

Comment: You should try posting this question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Depending how long you're gone, and how many scripts you have scheduled, is it too much just to delete the old events off your calendar? Assuming you have an iDevice. An on login script to delete all events older than today should work as well. It should trigger before the "old" ones

Comment: Since you can't know, in the script, which events triggers it, I suggest you to record in a log file the last run time stamp. at beginning of the script, you read the last time in the log file and, if too close from current time, you exit the script.